# PayPal recurring payments: How to show transaction details in checkout page

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have setup recurring payments in Paypal for my website using REST API. For one time payment, I know how to display transaction details by providing values for `item_list` (as in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/). However I don't know what values we should provide so that recurring payment profile will be shown on checkout page as well. Right now the only information shown is subscription agreement description.

[image: This is checkout page for one time payment with transaction details]
[image: Recurring payments. No agreement details shown]

How to add subscription details like recurring payment amount, initial payment amount etc to the checkout page? Thanks a million!

Comment: Post a sample call you're making

Comment: I created a payment plan then billing agreement with the request content the same as request sample in PayPal Rest API reference [https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-plan]

Comment: I have the same problem, @Thu did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a custom checkout page? using the **landing_page_type** with **Billing** value can make it work with much more then just recurring payments display...

Comment: I believe, that is not the right parameter. For me, it just changes the right side of paypal - if I set it to `Billing`, it shows new user signup form. Other options are `Login`, which shows login form, and `None` which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. This is how I deal with it for the moment:

I set the pricing information as string text into the description field of Agreement.

The down side is:

- A maximum of 127 characters is allowed in the description field.
- No format, no line break, just plain text.

But it is better than nothing.